# Getting a runtime warning in Python: coroutine was never awaited

Tags: python, discord.py

I was trying to create a discord bot and was facing some issues with Coroutines and Threads (Unless I'm missing a solution or not understanding Coroutines enough, separate threads are basically the only way my bot can operate)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import threading

# Defined Variables here

@client.event
async def on_ready():
"""Create a time Thread. The need for the thread is that you need the bot to be able to access the on_message function even when the time for loop is 
running"""

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
"""This function updates the said variables when someone dms the bot with note of the sender and what they sent""""
    
def time():
"""This function runs an infinite loop which checks whether the set number of days have passed"""
```

I hope this gives the basic idea of what the program is supposed to do.

#### The Issue

Part of my code needs to send a message to a specific channel, from the time function, which requires the need for

```
await client.get_channel(id=ID).send(f"{input}")
```

which requires time to be async.

However, if I make the time function async, I get another issue being that time is not awaited from the on_ready function. This is the exact message I get

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'time' was never awaited

I'm unable to await the thread either, I even tried creating a task using asyncio and trying to await that but even that failed. How would I go about solving this issue?

Comment: Have you looked into the multiproccess module? Using a multiproccess pipe might be a good solution since its duplex and can send messages between processes.

Comment: Do you mean use the multiprocessing module to create the process instead of threading? Because I'm not fully sure how sending messages between processes would help me since I want both my threads to remain separate (apologies if it wasn't clear in the post).